# android - Holo button looks different between versions

Tags: android, user-interface, button, themes

I have an android app with min sdk version 14.

in my `values-v14` folder, in `styles.xml` I have this:

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button"></style>
```

I apply this style to two buttons in one of my activities (the activity looks like a  big dialog).

I run the app on:

- OnePlus phone **(version 4.4.4 - api 19)**
- GT-I8190 **(version 4.1.2 - api 16)**

For some reason the buttons look different in color, which is weird because the **Holo** Theme should be available in **API 14 and above** (and both phones are above 14).

Small difference but its there (in the **OnePlus** the buttons are darker and in the **GT** they are lighter). **Why is it like that? shouldn't it be the same?**

**OnePlus Image:**

[image]

**GT-I8190 Image:**

[image]

**-----------------  EDIT - Adding Code  --------------------**

Here is the xml file with the buttons **(not_allowed_dialog.xml).**

As you can see, there isn't any drawables in the button or anywhere else.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/not_logged_in_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Please log in to add a ride"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/not"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/not_logged_in_text_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="5.0dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/not_allowed_login"
            style="@style/MyButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="Login Now!" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/not_allowed_register"
            style="@style/MyButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="Register Now!" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Also - Activity code:**

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity {
    private Button toRegisterBtn, toLoginBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.not_allowed_dialog);
        setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
        toRegisterBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.not_allowed_register);
        toLoginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.not_allowed_login);

        toRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
                finish();
            }
        });

        toLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show some code. Maybe drawable folders are not managed properly. you have to provide proper background image for hdpi,dpi,dpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi or whatever resolutions you want to support.

Comment: thanks for your answer. edited my question